# Wrong table name in scope response

Tags: smart-contract, table, get-table

My contract has two tables `mcat` and `mcatmig`.

Problem: scope request return wrong table name `mcat........1` instead of `mcatmig`:

```
% cleos get scope teresacode
{
"rows": [{
    "code": "teresacode",
    "scope": "default",
    "table": "mcat",
    "payer": "teresacode",
    "count": 5688
    },{
    "code": "teresacode",
    "scope": "default",
    "table": "mcat........1",
    "payer": "teresacode",
    "count": 2844
    }
],
"more": ""
}
```

And there is no table with that name:

```
% cleos get table teresacode default "mcat........1"
Error 3060003: Contract Table Query Exception
Most likely, the given table doesn't exist in the blockchain.
Error Details:
Unsupported table name: mcat........1
```

And real table is accessible fine:

```
% cleos get table teresacode default "mcatmig"
{
"rows": [],
"more": false,
"next_key": ""
}
```

I believe this happened after copying a large number of rows from table `mcat` to table `mcatmig`.

Something like that:

```
[[eosio::action]] void mcat::move(int count) {
    mcat_t mcat{get_self(), name{"default"}};
    mcatmig_t mcatmig{get_self(), name{"default"}};

    auto it = mcat.begin();
    int i = 0;
    while(i < count && it != mcat.end()) {
        mcatmig.emplace(...);
        i++;
        mcat.erase(it);
        it = mcat.begin();
    }
}
```

Why scope request return weird table name?
Is this a data corruption, `move` algorithm has a bug? Or it is an eosio bug? What do you think?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your multi_index table has multiple indices by using `indexed_by`, additional index will be shown like `ORIGINAL_TABLE_NAME........1`. The last character will use remaining last 4 bits in `eosio::name`. This is why additional indices can exist up to 16. (4 bits, 0 - 15 will be translated into `.`, `1-5`, `a-j`)

If you show the struct declarations and typedefs of `mcat` and `mcatmig`, I can answer more accurately.

Comment: You are awesome! Thank you! Is that even documented?

Comment: I haven't seen documentation which explains this topic in detail. I got this information by analyzing source code by myself. :)